# Public Key is not available

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, ros, robotics

I am trying to install ROS Kinetic on the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running Raspbian GNU7Linux 8 (Jessie) following these [steps](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi).

Setting up the repositories I get this output:

```
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.vAO4o1tMMY --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 0xB01FA11
```

And when trying to run a sudo apt-get update I get this error:

```
W: GPG error: http://packages.ros.org jessie InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5523BAEEB01FA116
```

Anyone had this problem adding a public key?

Answer (score 8):

Solved it.

This manually adds the key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <key number>    

sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, this could fix:

```
sudo apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring

sudo apt-key update

sudo apt-get update
```